# Button Positioning & Drop Up Menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

back again with another question. I am creating a navigation bar. My last child, account, I want to be positioned at the bottom of the menu without affecting size or positioning of the other li elements within the menu. I've tried many things, but think that the `relative` positioning of the parent is messing with the child's positioning. Also, when it gets to the bottom, I need the drop-down to be a drop-up. Figure you could show me a few pointers? Thank you in advance! :) Here is my code and the [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fa3uq/1/)

```
<div class="logo"></div>

<ul class="menu">
  <li title="Dashboard"><a href="#" class="active dashboard"><i class="fa">     
</i>Dashboard</a></li>
  <li title="Servers"><a href="#" class="servers"><i class="fa"></i>Servers</a>
        <ul>
        <li class="title">Servers</li>
        <li><a href="#" class="active">View Virtual Servers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Add Virtual Server</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  <li title="Clients"><a href="#" class="clients"><i class="fa"></i>Clients</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Clients</li>
            <li><a href="#">View Clients</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Add Client</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  <li title="Billing"><a href="#" class="billing"><i class="fa"></i>Billing</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Billing</li>
            <li><a href="#">View Orders</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Add New Order</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Transactions List</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">View Invoices</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  <li title="Support Tickets"><a href="#" class="supptickets"><i class="fa"></i>Support Tickets</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Support Tickets</li>
            <li><a href="#">All Tickets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Open Tickets</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Answered Tickets</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>  
  <li title="IPBlocks"><a href="#" class="ipblocks"><i class="fa"></i>IP Blocks</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="title">IP Blocks</li>
            <li><a href="#">View IP Blocks</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Add IPV4 Block</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Add IPV6 Block</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  <li title="Nodes"><a href="#" class="nodes"><i class="fa"></i>Nodes</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Nodes</li>
            <li><a href="#">View Nodes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Add Nodes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Node Groups</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  <li title="Plans"><a href="#" class="plans"><i class="fa"></i>Plans</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Plans</li>
            <li><a href="#">View Plans</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Add Plan</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  <li title="Settings"><a href="#" class="settings"><i class="fa"></i>Settings</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Settings</li>
            <li><a href="#">Configuration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Email Templates</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Administrators</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">API Access</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">System Backup</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Backup Servers</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  <li title="Tools"><a href="#" class="tools"><i class="fa"></i>Tools</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Tools</li>
            <li><a href="#">Database</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sessions</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  <li title="Logs"><a href="#" class="logs"><i class="fa"></i>Logs</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Logs</li>
            <li><a href="#">System Messages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Client Log</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Client Activity</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Admin Log</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Authentication Log</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">API Log</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">System Email Log</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  <li title="Reports"><a href="#" class="reports"><i class="fa"></i>Reports</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Reports</li>
            <li><a href="#">Annual Income Report</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Monthly Sales</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Product Sales</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">New Customers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Server Uptime</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  <li title="Account"><a href="#" class="account"><i class="fa"></i>Account</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="title">Account</li>
            <li><a href="#">Change Password</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
  </li>
  </ul>
```

css

```
    @import url('http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'); /* Le Font Awesome Iconz */
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300); /* Le Font */
/* Le Main Menu */
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 64px;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #303641;
    z-index:10;  
    box-shadow: 2px 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow:    2px 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 0 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
.menu > li {
    position: relative;
}

.menu > li > a {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -500em;
    height: 2.5em;
    width: 4em;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    text-align: center;
    color: #aaabae;
    position: relative;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(170, 171, 174, 0.15);
}
/* Le Logo */
.logo {
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #303641 url('../img/logo.png') no-repeat center;
    height: 4em;
    width: 4em;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 11;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(170, 171, 174, 0.15);
    box-shadow: 2px -6px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    -moz-box-shadow:    2px -6px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px -6px 18px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
/* Flyout */
.menu ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 4em;
    width: 10em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
.menu li:hover ul li a {
    display: block;
    background: #2b303a;
    color: #aaabae;
    line-height: 3em;
    width: 18.7em;
    padding-left: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans:300', sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(170, 171, 174, 0.15);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(170, 171, 174, 0.15);
    border-right: none;
}
.title {
    display: block;
    background: #303641;
    color: #aaabae;
    line-height: 3.4em;
    width: 18.7em;
    padding-left: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans:300', sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(170, 171, 174, 0.15);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(170, 171, 174, 0.0);
    border-right: none;
}
/* Le Flyout Box Corner Radius */
.menu li:hover ul li:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 0.3em;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0.3em;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0.3em;
}
.menu li:hover ul li:last-child a {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3em;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0.3em;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3em;
}
.menu li:hover ul li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.0);
}
/* Le Menu Icons */
.menu li a i:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    padding-top: 1em;
    speak: none;
    text-indent: 0em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: .8em;
}
.menu li a.servers i:before {
  content: "\f0c2";
}
.menu li a.nodes i:before {
  content: "\f1b3";
}
.menu li a.clients i:before {
  content: "\f0c0";
}
.menu li a.supptickets i:before {
  content: "\f0e0";
}
.menu li a.ipblocks i:before {
  content: "\f009";
}
.menu li a.dashboard i:before {
  content: "\f0e4";
}
.menu li a.plans i:before {
  content: "\f03a";
}
.menu li a.settings i:before {
  content: "\f085";
}
.menu li a.tools i:before {
  content: "\f0ad";
}
.menu li a.logs i:before {
  content: "\f15c";
}
.menu li a.billing i:before {
  content: "\f155";
}
.menu li a.reports i:before {
  content: "\f080";
}
.menu li a.account i:before {
  content: "\f007";
}
/* Le Hover & Active States */
.menu li a:hover {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.menu li ul li a:hover {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    transition: color 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.menu li a.active {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
.menu li:hover ul li a.active {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: "*... I want to be positioned at the bottom of the menu...*": it **is** at the bottom. What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: As in, aligned with the bottom of the screen, not simple inline and below the other li elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible by via CSS.

You need jquery to do the trick.

```
$(function () {
    var lastEle = $("ul > li[title]:last-child").offset().top;
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    if (lastEle > windowHeight) {
        var numberOfLi = $("ul > li[title]").length;
        var heightOfLi = ((windowHeight - 65) / numberOfLi);
        $("ul > li[title]").css({
            height: heightOfLi
        });
    } else {
        $("ul > li[title]:last-child")
            .css({
            position: "absolute",
            bottom: "65px",
            "border-top": "1px solid rgba(170, 171, 174, 0.15)"
        });
    }

    $("li").hover(function () {
        var liHeight = $(this).offset().top;
        var ulHeight = $(this).find("ul").height();
        if ((windowHeight - liHeight) < ulHeight) {
            $(this).find('ul').css({
                bottom: 0,
                top: "inherit"
            });
        } else {
            $(this).find('ul').css({
                bottom: "inherit",
                top: 0
            });

        }
    });
});
```

It's not only for the `Accounts` but also for all links at the bottom.

According to your current design, Any links with submenu at the bottom are getting hidden.  So this script will check the height and either drop up or down based on the height of the screen.

**[---> DEMO <---](http://jsbin.com/naviz/7)**

Comment: Script looks good, but last li child is still not aligned at the bottom of the screen, so I cannot see the functionality (whether it changes to drop-up or not).

Comment: Yes, It's because you are using position:fixed. But the menu has too many items. If you want to check the functionality: press ctrl & - together. so it will zoom out. WIth that you can check the functionality

Comment: Zooming out is not changing anything between drop-up/down.
The second part of my question was how to align the last child (user) to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Awesome! As far as the functionality of the script goes you have it spot on.
Could you possibly have the answer to the second part of my question? How to get the <li title="account"> button in the menu to be aligned with the bottom of the screen at all times, separated from the rest of the buttons?

Comment: So if your issue is resolved, you can mark it as answer

Comment: As I said above, you answered half my question beautifully. But the second part still goes unanswered. How can I get the button <li title="account"> in the menu to be aligned with the bottom of the screen at all times, separated from the rest of the buttons, so that there is space between "reports" button and "user" button?